# The "this question has been closed" message is misleading

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

When I am viewing a question, and it has been closed, this message will pop up:

> This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted.

What it actually means is that I can't post an answer anymore. But don't you think the word `accepted` is ambiguous? "no more answers will be accepted" can also mean that the OP cannot click on the accept checkmark anymore, which the OP *can* do. I found this rather confusing.

What about changing the message to

> This question has been closed - no more answers can be posted.

or

> This question has been closed - you can't post an answer now.

Comment: Meh - at the point where you understand what "accepted" means in a Stack Overflow context, you also understand what "closed" means and how "accepted" is to be understood here. Your 1st suggestion sounds good though, also better for ESL users

Comment: "you can no longer post an answer"

Comment: @Pekka웃: Meh - "you know what I meant" isn't a good reason not to fix obviously broken wording, especially when "you know what I meant" isn't provably, universally true.

Comment: I like "no more answers [may] be posted".

Comment: @CodyGray "you can no longer post an answer" could be understood that YOU can no longer post an answer, though. The passive form seems more universal

Comment: You *can* http post an answer to any question regardless of whether it is closed or not. It is the server that decides whether or not to accept it so "accepted" seems less broken than "posted" IMO.

Comment: Maybe "no more answers can be added"

Comment: Technically, it's not "closed", it's "on hold". If we're going to edit the message, we need to fix all the issues ;)

Comment: Your efforts are futile. If it was rephrased to "no more answers can be added", it would still not be true. There's a short grace period after the question is put on hold.

Comment: @AndrasDeak but when that message appears, the post answer is disabled though

Comment: @Sweeper: Anyone can (and sometimes will) remove the `disabled` attribute, and AFAIK the apps don't pay attention to it either.

Comment: It's clear from the context that it is  `1. to take or receive (something offered); receive with approval or favor: to accept a present; to accept a proposal.`, not `7. to regard as true or sound; believe: `. ([Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/accepted))

Comment: "This question has been put on hold - no more answers will be allowed"

Comment: The objections strike me as making perfect the enemy of good.  Whether or not there are other changes that need to be made, and even if the proposed wording is not perfect, it is better and should be done.

Comment: @WayneConrad note that the question has +36-7 score, I think most people are just occupying themselves with discussion in the thread. I don't think there are any serious objections.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit yeah, on further thinking this needs to be changed, agreed

Comment: @WayneConrad: If you're going to do a job, do it properly. There's no harm in trying to get this _right_ while we're making the change.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: "No more answers may be added" is true within the abstraction presented by the interface. Of course there are ways around that (such as hacking Stack Exchange's database servers) but we need not enumerate all of those. A good place to draw the line is where the SE software intends for you to stop asking questions.

Comment: @MartinSmith: "Posted" is an obvious synonym for "successfully posted" in this case and I don't think you'll find anyone who'll be confused there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - In other words *Meh - "you know what I meant"*

Comment: @MartinSmith: I _knew_ you were going to say that. The difference is that, in this case, everyone _will_ know what you meant. That's not true of the text discussed in the question.

Comment: I expect this Q to reach the 100 net votes before it falls off the CB, happy ridding the bike shed bike :D

Comment: @Braiam The bike shed should be painted blue

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *"accepted"* is ambiguous. Virtually any of the commentators' proposed replacements would be better. Suggested rewording:

> This question has been closed -- answers cannot be added to closed questions.

Or, more curtly:

> Question closed: answers can't be added.

Note: the word "*more*" is avoided because there may be no answers, and "*more*" implies at least one answer exists.

Comment: Just to note: the text for CW locked posts is: "This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*" - So that one appears to have gone done the *added* route.

Comment: @NinjaPuppy, redundantly yet:  _'No **add**itional answers can be **add**ed'_, but changing *'s/additional/new/'* would make sense.

Comment: _"more implies at least one answer exists."_ Not really; more than zero is a thing. IMO it's idiomatic English in this context to use "no more", "no further" etc, regardless of the current quantity.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, see [Does “No more” by necessity imply there was some before?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44667/does-no-more-by-necessity-imply-there-was-some-before)

Comment: @agc: As a native speaker I cannot more strongly dispute the conclusion that answerer has reached. It would certainly not be the first time an ELU post was full of abject nonsense. You should also note that the context is completely different (ownership statement, not ability declaration)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, rather than complain about ELU *here*, perhaps you should dispute it more strongly *there*.

Comment: @agc: You used a link to ELU as a counterargument to my claim; disputing the validity of that counterargument _here_ is precisely the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, to the contrary, ELU is deprived of your corrections, which if you then provided, that same ELU link might soon better support your own opinions than mine.

Comment: @agc: So you post a claim, then when someone argues against your claim, you complain for that person to argue it elsewhere instead? Truly bizarre. This conversation is no longer productive; downvoted due to reasoning above & have a nice day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122676/discussion-between-agc-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: No; I repeat: this conversation is no longer productive; have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

During the downtime a few moments ago, SE told me "This site is currently not accepting new answers." Seemed like good phrasing. Maybe we should use that here, too?

> This question has been closed - no new answers may be posted.